# ssh_config: Keys named after server hostnames

Tags: ssh, openssh

My current `.ssh/config` file simply contains the following:

```
Host *
HostName %h
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h
```

This allows me to connect to every machine using the key with the same name as the hostname of the remote machine.

However, when I connect to a server for which I don't yet have a key or simply can't set one, the SSH client shows a "No such identity" warning.

Is there a way to suppress this warning using either an entry in the config file or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Match exec` to run the same `test` aka `[` command that you would in a shell:

```
Match exec "[ -e ~/.ssh/%h ]"
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%h
```

(This starts a new section in the same way as `Host` does, and has the same precedence.)

`Hostname %h` is redundant; that's already the default value.

Comment: Wow thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.